# Why content after the canvas element is invisible?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have created one html page with the contents ,that contains Canvas,navbar,image But the contents after the Canvas elements is not visible.

**index.html**

```
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<canvas id="canvas"   onmousewheel="return zoom()"/>  
<img src="logo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `<canvas>` isn't a self-closing element. You need to use `<canvas></canvas>`:

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
<canvas id="canvas" onmousewheel="return zoom()"></canvas>  
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" />
```